# How can I keep the original index of each element after setting a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, set

I have two lists `list_1` and `list_2` of equal size containing 40 elements each. I found that I can map the corresponding remaining fields after the set by using

```
list(dict(zip(list_1, list_2)).items())
```

Example:

```
list_1 = [ 'Bob', 'Johnson', '', '','25' ,'USA']
list_2 = [ 'Dan',  '', '','', '','UK']
```

Output using previous code:

```
out_list = [ ('Bob','Dan'), ('Johnson',''), ('25',''), ('USA','UK')]
```

( This is the desired output ! But I also want the index list as seen below)

I want to also store the original index (two elements have the same index since they are mapped together) of each pair.

`index_list = [ 0, 1, 4 ,5]`   (elements with indexes 2 and 3 where discarded)

How can I do that?

Comment: `list(zip(list_1, list_2))` ? The `dict` call means only unique keys are stored (and they're not ordered generally)

Comment: @Chris_Rands without dict the list is not set

Comment: You'll need to be clearer, what *should* `out_list` be?

Comment: `out_list` does contain an entry with key `''` (it looks like `[('', ''), ('Johnson', ''), ('25', ''), ('Bob', 'Dan'), ('USA', 'UK')]`, order excepted). Do you do something else to remove that or do you leave it in and should it be included in the output?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sorry if i wasn't clear,  I want to create index_list of the set elements that are contained in output list. Confusing naming my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply use one of the list for this as follows:

```
 index_list = [list_1.index(each) for each in list_1 if each]

 output : [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Much more efficient to use `enumerate()` to get the index than to index the list each time

Comment: You should also be aware this solution only excludes keys based on them being empty. If there were duplicate non empty keys the dupes would not be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OrderedDict from collections.

```
import collections
list(collections.OrderedDict(zip(list_1,list_2)).items())
```

Comment: You can use OrderedDict from collections.

Answer (score 0):

The key of dictionnary must be unique and not null, for that raison elements with indexes 2 and 3 discarded, if you want to display all elements try

```
zip(list1, list_2)
```

and the output will :

```
[('Bob', 'Dan'), ('Johnson', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('25', ''), ('USA', 'UK')]
```